# Is Magento Contact Us comments are saved in database table?

Tags: php, magento

In my `Magento Contact Us` Page, there are `name, email, telephone and comment` fields.  If an user fill all fields and click `submit` button an email will go the specified email address(given in email options section in admin panel).

I think this is the working flow of Contact Us Page.

My question is: `Is the inserted comments are saved in database table?` 
And `How can the admin can view the comments, sender details via back end?`

I need the comments and suggestion in database table..How can I achieve this?

Please help me...My **Magento version** is **1.9.0.1**

Answer (score 1):

NO contacts form information does not save in database, in order to save this information in DB you have to override contacts module.